# Pygears - Unresolved array argument when instantianting component

Tags: python, pygears

I am trying to implement and simulate a simple adder component that doubles the input value. Bellow is my code.

```
from pygears.typing import Uint
from pygears.hdl import *
from pygears.sim import sim
from pygears.lib import drv

@gear
def add(x):
    return x + x
    
    
@gear
async def collect(din, result):
    async with din as val:
        result.append(val)
    
    
result = []
drv(t=Uint[16], seq=[0, 1, 2, 3]) | add() | collect(result=result)

hdlgen('/adder', outdir='sv/adder_svlib')

sim('/adder')
```

After attempting to run this code, I get the following error:

```
 File "test.py", line 34, in <module>
    drv(t=Uint[16], seq=[0, 1, 2, 3]) | add() | collect(result=result)
GearArgsNotSpecified: [0], Unresolved argument "[]" connected to the input "result"
 - when instantiating "collect"
```

Why is this argument unresolved? I have seen a similar implementation in the "echo" example, where in the function wav_echo_sim an empty array was passed to the collecting gear in order to store the values.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of gear (function) arguments that are distinguished in PyGears:

- interfaces - which can be specified using either positional or keyword (named) arguments, and
- compile-time parameters - which need to be declared as keyword-only

In your example, the `collect` gear expects a Python list for the `result` argument, but the `result` argument is not declared as keyword-only, so PyGears expects to get an interface there, hence the error message. Your gear should be declared as follows (notice the asterisk '*' between the two arguments):

```
@gear
async def collect(din, *, result):
    async with din as val:
        result.append(val)
```

In other words, interfaces and non-interface arguments should be separated by an asterisk '*'.

Next, your hdlgen call will not work, since there is no such gear instance called "adder". I guess you wanted to generate HDL files for the `add` gear instance. By default, instances get the same name as the gear definition function, so in your case, the instance will be named "add". You can either explicitly specify instance name like this:

```
drv(t=Uint[16], seq=[0, 1, 2, 3]) | add(name="adder") | collect(result=result)
```

or change the path specified for `hdlgen` to:

```
hdlgen('/add', outdir='sv/adder_svlib')
```

Last, the first argument for the `sim` call is the path of the directory where simulation artifacts should be placed (like waveforms, generated HDL files, logs...), so you should either"

- leave it empty - in which case a temporary folder will be used, or
- specify a valid absolute or relative path